# New update - voice messages whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp

Recently i have updated whatsapp and i can't open voice messages anymore ... What is wrong . Fix it please . I reseted The phone and tried everything . I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: This sounds like a bug with WhatsApp, rather than a Windows Phone issue?